# how to call the built-in notification system in the OS(Android,iphone) using  phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I created notification icon using system notification plugin in android phonegap.But Now I want to call the built-in notification system in the OS(Android,iphone) using android phonegap. please guide me
thanks in advance.

Comment: question not clear. pls elaborate

Comment: What do you mean "built notification system"

Comment: every mobile contain notification.My question is how to call that notification using phonegap.please tell me the solution.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about local notification like alerts, confirms... in PhoneGap you need to take a look at [PhoneGap API : Notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#Notification)

If you're talking about notification that are sent from a server to the device you need to take a look a Push Notification tutorials for Android

Which one are you trying to implement ?

Comment: I want to show notification icon in both foreground and background.I used this phonegap API, It display alert.how to display this alert in both foreground and background,please tell me the solution.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> navigator.notification.alert("")

or

> alert("")

to show the notifications.
 Using these commands phonegap will will inoke native notifications(Like for Android it will invoke alert dialog).

Comment: I want to show notification icon in both foreground and background.I used this phonegap API, It display alert.how to display this alert in both foreground and background,please tell me the solution.thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want. Can you be little more elaborative and try to explain through some example....

Comment: I got the notification icon in status bar both when application running in foreground and background using system notification plugin in android phonegap.Same like that i need to get the notification alert.I used navigator.notification.alert("").It displayed only in foreground.But also I need get the notification alert in background.please guide me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting the following code into a html and ran it and I uploaded it in my server and opened the link in my Safari browser in my iPhone and the clicked on Show Confirm and no window popups up!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://mobile-web-development-with-phonegap.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/svn-history/r99/trunk/com.mds.apg/resources/phonegap/js/phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Wait for PhoneGap to load
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        // PhoneGap is ready        
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Empty
        }
        // process the confirmation dialog result
        function onConfirm(button) {
            alert('You selected button ' + button);
        }
        // Show a custom confirmation dialog
                function showConfirm() {
            navigator.notification.confirm(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
        );
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showConfirm(); return false;">Show Confirm</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```